# Tensorflow gather_nd over input with varied shape

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensor

I need to extract the the sub tensors along `axis=1` based on the value from another tensor.

```py
state = tf.placeholder(shape=[None, None, 10], dtype=tf.float32)
length = tf.placeholder(shape=[None], dtype=tf.int32)

# this won't work, just be put here to demonstrate what I need
next_init_state = state[:, length - 1, :]
```

if `state` and `length` have deterministic shape, then `next_init_state` can be derived through `gather_nd`

```py
state = tf.placeholder(shape=[10, 10, 10], dtype=tf.float32)
length = tf.placeholder(shape=[10], dtype=tf.int32)

index = tf.stack([tf.range(0, 10), length])
next_init_state = tf.gather_nd(state, index)
```

However since state and length all have nondeterministic shape `None` in the problem I have, the `gather_nd` approach won't work. At least I cannot think of a way to make it work. Is there any way to address it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized this is actually solved by Tensorflow's higher order function.

```
tf.map_fn(lambda x: x[0][x[1], :], (state, length), dtype=tf.float32)
```